# HTML Display an Resized Image maintaning Ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image from a URL and I want that image to have a given size but I want to maintain the ratio between height and width.

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
img {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="http://..." height="100" />
```

No magic here, although client-side resizing usually looks crappy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to style an image

i believe if you use px for example, and specify only one dimension

```
img {width:100px}
```

the ratio is usually maintained

You can use

```
img {width:100px;height:auto;}
```

which may help

if you use

```
img {width:100px}
```

the ratio is maintained in IE 7 at least